# Converting time from string to integer type

Tags: c++

```
while(token != NULL)
{
    if(stoi(token) >= 1 && stoi(token) <= 255)
    {
        valid ++;
    }

    token = std::strtok(NULL, ".");
}
```

I was working for a program that reads user inputs and decides whether the inputs are IP addresses, or not.
This part of the program is to separate the address into tokens(i.e. line of numbers), and see if each token is a group of numeric numbers. The inside variable `valid` is a flag variable to make sure that program enters in this block and counts the times of enter.

My entire code runs fine, but the online compiler shows extraordinary execution time, which confused me a lot.

I am now trying to fix my program by focusing to this part, because the rest of the part is very simple.

In a programmer's point of view, what takes so much time?

Comment: Your question title is a little misleading, since you're not converting anything really, and it's definitely not about times.

Comment: Besides that (and also unrelated to your problem) you don't validate IPv4 addresses correctly. Remember that it is allowed to have zeros in an address. Think for example about `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: What is `stoi`?

Comment: "*what takes so much time?*" Why don't you profile it and find out for sure?

Comment: Yes, you are right... I did not think of it...

Comment: As for your problem, it's really hard to say. Are you *sure* this is the code that's causing the online compiled program to be slow? What else are you doing in your code? Maybe it's the online system that is slow or impose execution slowdowns to be able to handle more clients?

Comment: `stoi` converts string to integer

Comment: @melpomene [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol)

Comment: Does online compiler causes the program to be slow instead of I making time slow?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Oh. I didn't realize we had that (and the code calls it without `std::`, unlike `std::strtok`).

Comment: Those `stoi` calls look suspicious. Each call implicitly constructs a `std::string` object from `token`, converts it to an `int`, then destroys the `std::string` again. And you're doing this twice for each token, which is unnecessary. But as Some programmer dude said, why do you think it's this part of the code that's slow?